# Read the XML data Nodes in TSQL Query and filter the XML columns data

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I Have a TABLE in that one filed have XML data, below I have provided and I need to read this fields and filter the data in SQL QUery, Can someone help to read below select list fields?

XML is:

```
<Order
    xmlns:Order="http://www.hp.com/namespaces/iscs/base/ordermanagement/ois/schemas/order_xml" 
    UniqueId="" Id="SCEO37600056" Name="" DisplayName="" 
    Description="" ShopperId="0c52f72f-d24d-492b-89e8-a8f433b652b1" 
    SerializationVersion="1.0.0" SourceCode="" 
    CustomerId="SCEU33684387" CustomerEmail="administratie@entis.ai" 
    TaxLogic="DRC" DefaultTaxRate="21" OrderEDDMessage="UnKnown" 
    QuoteCreatedOn="1901-01-01T00:00:00" OrderKey="SCEO37600056" 
    CurrencyCode="EUR" Language="nl" 
    CurrentApplication="NLSMBCallCenter" IPAddress="" 
    DiscountType="None" CanProcess="false" AccountId="SCEA3258" 
    CatalogName="NL Public (CG1926)" Tier1="false" 
    ExternalAccountId="" CustomerName="Tineke van Westrenen" 
    CompanyName="Default Public Account" SalesRepId="SCEU33285893" 
    QuoteId="" AgentId="" AgentLogin="" QuoteCreatedBy="" 
    OrderCreatedBy="" QuoteCreatedDate="1901-01-01T00:00:00" 
    CommunityId="SCESG23099" 
    InternalComments="DYN_BUNDLE_0008162_6B8D6EA_ABH on BC pricePGS Fraud Review&#xA; -- Order removed from RMS Hold - X Minute Services -- Order released - X Minute Services " 
    ExternalComments="" 
    PSTQSTExemptionCode="" GSTHSTExemptionCode="" 
    InvoiceComments="" PurchaseStatus="" PrimaryUse="" 
    CatalogId="CG1926" BillingBlock="false" 
    ReceivedInvoice="false" BusinessPipeline="" 
    CustomerRequestedDeliveryDate="" CustomerRequestedDeliveryTime="" 
    BypassAvaialblility="false" BypassAvaialblilityReason="" 
    CustomerSegment="Business" ProcessingType="Regular" 
    SendSiebel="false" AssociateOpportunity="" 
    CheckInventory="true" IsInventoryAvailable="false" 
    CountryKey="NL" Region="EMEA" ApplyForRecycleServices="" 
    RegisterForInternetServiceProvider="" RequestToIssueReceipt="" 
    ReceiveOrderStatusMails="" CanValidatePipeLine="true" 
    IsCCRepApproved="false" FulfillmentId="EU_Direct" 
    SourceCatalogKey="CAT-1157426" ShouldSettleBill="false" 
    IsPriceInclusiveofTax="true" IsFrozenQuote="false" 
    ShouldSettlePayPal="false" DiscountAllowanceExceeded="false"  
    DiscountAllowanceExceededAmount="0" 
    HasDisplayedDiscountExceededMsg="false" 
    PriceIncludesRegulatoryFee="false" 
    HasMultipleLSPFulfillment="false" 
    IsEDDMessageRequested="false" FulfillmentSegment="SMB" 
    FulfillmentSubSegment="Public" CustomerApprovalEmail="" 
    ClubName="" HasOutOfStockItem="false" ISDRCEligible="true" 
    ISDRCApplied="true" Doc_number="0087a107-49b337ac8-7" 
    ISVIESRequired="false" OrderWithSavedCardProfile="false" 
    Is3DSecure="false" IsValidGeoBlockingSoldtoCountry="false" 
    ISGeoBlockingApplied="false" ISGeoBlockingEligible="false" 
    GeoBlockingSoldToCountry="NL" OrderMethodType="ZCDO" 
    OrderType="Regular" OrderSource="ZISCSCC" Currency="" 
    Prefix="" DealDescriptor="NLEURSP" OrderCancelledBy="" 
    OrderStatus="Open" OrderDate="2022-11-22T14:48:55">

    <EffectiveStartDate>1901-01-01T00:00:00</EffectiveStartDate>
    <EffectiveEndDate>1901-01-01T00:00:00</EffectiveEndDate>
    <Status>Open</Status>
    <Created UniqueId="" Id="" ActionPerformed="Created" PerformedBy="AUTH\vanVegS" PerformedDate="2022-11-22T13:48:55.2475289+00:00" />
    <LastModified UniqueId="" Id="" ActionPerformed="Modified" PerformedBy="AUTH\vanVegS" PerformedDate="2022-11-22T13:48:58.3725983+00:00" />
    <ExtendedProperties />
    <ExpirationDate>2022-12-22T00:00:00</ExpirationDate>
    <OriginationSource>CallCenter</OriginationSource>
    <SubTotal UniqueId="" Id="" Amount="23137.97" />
    <BasePriceSubTotal UniqueId="" Id="" Amount="23137.8" />
    <Total UniqueId="" Id="" Amount="20874.57" />
    <Errors />
    <LineItems>
        <Item UniqueId="" Id="1" Name="" DisplayName="" Description="HP ZBook Firefly G9 mobiele workstation met NVIDIA® T500" OSSStatus="" GroupId="1" Quantity="10" ActualQty="0" AttachId="0" DynamicBunImageURL="" IsDisplayable="true" Availability="0" ValidatePrice="true" CurrentQty="0" FutureQty="-1" ReservationQty="0" EDD="TBA" FutureUsed="false" IsValid="true" CampaignCode="" TaxLogic="DRC" PriceIncludesRegulatoryFee="false" OID="0" DynamicBundleId="" DynamicBundleName="" DynamicBundleDescription="" Sequence="0" ActualLineItemId="1" IsDynamicBundle="false" DynamicBundleQty="0" IsCouponApplicable="false" ParentSku="" isTaxRateChanged="false" ItemMaxQty="0">
            <EffectiveStartDate>1901-01-01T00:00:00</EffectiveStartDate>
            <EffectiveEndDate>1901-01-01T00:00:00</EffectiveEndDate>
            <Status>Active</Status>
            <ExtendedProperties />
            <Product UniqueId="" Id="P498222" Name="HP ZBook Firefly G9 mobiele workstation met NVIDIA® T500" DisplayName="HP ZBook Firefly G9 mobiele workstation met NVIDIA® T500" Description="HP ZBook Firefly G9 mobiele workstation met NVIDIA® T500" CategoryId="" CategoryName="" OID="" Characteristics="" Sequence="0" PrimaryImage="https://www.hp.com/nl-nl/shop/Html/Merch/Images/c08249910_209x189.jpg" CatalogId="CG1926" ParentCategoryId="" HierarchyDescription="" Hierarchy="" FulfillmentId="EU_Direct" Expressflag="false" ApplicationType="" ConsumesInventory="true" IsProductTangible="true" IsConfigurable="true" CurrentEDD="TBA" FutureEDD="TBA" CurrentInventory="9" FutureInventory="0" ConfigBaseProductPartNumber="" PreferredProduct="false" Family="" ArfFlag="false" IsNonBuyable="false" IsExternal="false" FreeShipping="false" IsProductNew="false" PartNumber="6B8D6EA#ABH" MfgName="" Unspsc="43211503" ProductLine="IK" HTSCode="8471300000" IsAncillary="false" IsSameQtyReq="false" TaxCode="OV" ProductFamily="" ProductSource="" QuickAccessCode="" Qualifier="" IsActive="true" IsVirtual="false" IsSellable="false" IsStandAlone="false" DeliveryGroup="" FulfillmentSource="" CampaignCode="" EclipseId="" TaxRate="0" TaxType="OM" BigDealId="44301913" Quantity="1" WarrantyDesc="" PscLocale="" PscReferringUrl="" PscCrossSellUrl="" PscPartNumber="" LspSku="" LSPFulfillmentId="" OutOfStock="true" LeadTime="365" ETA="261" EDDMessage="ShipIn48Hours" ActualEDDMessage="UnKnown" FreeShippingOrder="false" DFlag="false" SourceCatalogId="" HasPromotions="false" HasDiscounts="false" DynBunId="">
            <EffectiveStartDate>1901-01-01T00:00:00</EffectiveStartDate>
            <EffectiveEndDate>1901-01-01T00:00:00</EffectiveEndDate>
            <Status>Active</Status>
            <ExtendedProperties />
            <AttachId>0</AttachId>
            <CatalogItemType>Product</CatalogItemType>
            <CatalogItems />
            <Specifications />
            <MetadataList>
                <Metadata UniqueId="" Id="" Name="MarketingText" Value="" Sequence="0">
                    <MetadataType>Specification</MetadataType>
                </Metadata>
                <Metadata UniqueId="" Id="" Name="XmlContentText" Value="" Sequence="0">
                    <MetadataType>Specification</MetadataType>
                </Metadata>
            </MetadataList>
            <MetadataGroups />
            <Promotions />
            <Surcharge UniqueId="" Id="" Amount="0" />
            <CopyrightFee UniqueId="" Id="" Amount="0" />
            <ProductType>Bto</ProductType>
            <Discount
                    xmlns:d6p1="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" d6p1:type="OperatorDiscount" UniqueId="" Id="" Name="" DisplayName="" Description="" Code="" ApplyToLocation="Unknown" DiscountType="FixedAmount" ReasonCode="Deal price approval" Value="64.64" MinimumApplicableAmount="0" MaximumApplicableAmount="0">
                    <EffectiveStartDate>1901-01-01T00:00:00</EffectiveStartDate>
                    <EffectiveEndDate>1901-01-01T00:00:00</EffectiveEndDate>
                    <ApprovalId />
                </Discount>
            </ProductDiscount>
            <PscSegment>unknown</PscSegment>
            <BaseCatalogPrice UniqueId="" Id="" Amount="2152" />
            <BaseListPrice UniqueId="" Id="" Amount="2152" />
            <ListPrice UniqueId="" Id="" Amount="2603.92" />
            <CatalogFinalPrice UniqueId="" Id="" Amount="2603.92" />
            <PriceType>Unknown</PriceType>
        </Product>
        <ExternalInfo UniqueId="" Id="" Name="" DisplayName="" Description="" ProductColor="" ProductURL="" AccessoryURL="" ImageURL="" ProductLine="" ProductFamily="">
            <EffectiveStartDate>1901-01-01T00:00:00</EffectiveStartDate>
            <EffectiveEndDate>1901-01-01T00:00:00</EffectiveEndDate>
            <Status>Active</Status>
            <ExtendedProperties />
        </ExternalInfo>
        <LineItemDiscountCollection>
            <Discount
                xmlns:d5p1="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" d5p1:type="OperatorDiscount" UniqueId="" Id="" Name="" DisplayName="" Description="" Code="" ApplyToLocation="Item" DiscountType="FixedAmount" ReasonCode="Deal price approval" Value="-646.4" MinimumApplicableAmount="0" MaximumApplicableAmount="0">
                <EffectiveStartDate>1901-01-01T00:00:00</EffectiveStartDate>
                <EffectiveEndDate>1901-01-01T00:00:00</EffectiveEndDate>
                <Status>Active</Status>
                <ExtendedProperties />
                <Message />
                <DiscountTaxFactor UniqueId="" Id="" Amount="0" />
                <TypeOfDiscount>Operator</TypeOfDiscount>
                <RequestorSalesRepId />
                <ApproverSalesRepId />
                <ApprovalId />
            </Discount>
        </LineItemDiscountCollection>
        <TaxItems>
            <LineItemTax UniqueId="" Id="0" Message="" Code="OM" Type="Product">
                <TotalAmount UniqueId="" Id="" Amount="0" />
                <SubTaxes>
                    <LineItemTaxLevel UniqueId="" Id="0">
                        <_amount UniqueId="" Id="" Amount="0" />
                        <_level />
                        <_code>OM</_code>
                        <_type>OM</_type>
                        <_message />
                        <_rate>21</_rate>
                        <_certificateNumber />
                    </LineItemTaxLevel>
                </SubTaxes>
            </LineItemTax>
        </TaxItems>
        <IsExclude>false</IsExclude>
        <LineItemApportionedDiscount UniqueId="" Id="" Amount="0" />
        <RefreshedProduct UniqueId="" Id="P498222" Name="HP ZBook Firefly G9 mobiele workstation met NVIDIA® T500" DisplayName="HP ZBook Firefly G9 mobiele workstation met NVIDIA® T500" Description="HP ZBook Firefly G9 mobiele workstation met NVIDIA® T500" CategoryId="" CategoryName="" OID="" Characteristics="" Sequence="0" PrimaryImage="https://www.hp.com/nl-nl/shop/Html/Merch/Images/c08249910_209x189.jpg" CatalogId="CG1926" ParentCategoryId="" HierarchyDescription="" Hierarchy="" FulfillmentId="EU_Direct" Expressflag="false" ApplicationType="" ConsumesInventory="true" IsProductTangible="true" IsConfigurable="true" CurrentEDD="TBA" FutureEDD="TBA" CurrentInventory="9" FutureInventory="0" ConfigBaseProductPartNumber="" PreferredProduct="false" Family="" ArfFlag="false" IsNonBuyable="false" IsExternal="false" FreeShipping="false" IsProductNew="false" PartNumber="6B8D6EA#ABH" MfgName="" Unspsc="43211503" ProductLine="IK" HTSCode="8471300000" IsAncillary="false" IsSameQtyReq="false" TaxCode="OM" ProductFamily="" ProductSource="" QuickAccessCode="" Qualifier="" IsActive="true" IsVirtual="false" IsSellable="false" IsStandAlone="false" DeliveryGroup="" FulfillmentSource="" CampaignCode="" EclipseId="" TaxRate="21" TaxType="OM" BigDealId="44301913" Quantity="1" WarrantyDesc="" PscLocale="" PscReferringUrl="" PscCrossSellUrl="" PscPartNumber="" LspSku="" LSPFulfillmentId="" OutOfStock="false" LeadTime="365" ETA="261" EDDMessage="ShipIn48Hours" ActualEDDMessage="UnKnown" FreeShippingOrder="false" DFlag="false" SourceCatalogId="" HasPromotions="false" HasDiscounts="false" DynBunId="">
            <EffectiveStartDate>1901-01-01T00:00:00</EffectiveStartDate>
            <EffectiveEndDate>1901-01-01T00:00:00</EffectiveEndDate>
            <Status>Active</Status>
            <ExtendedProperties />
            <AttachId>0</AttachId>
            <CatalogItemType>Product</CatalogItemType>
            <CatalogItems />
            <Specifications />
            <MetadataList>
                <Metadata UniqueId="" Id="" Name="MarketingText" Value="" Sequence="0">
                    <MetadataType>Specification</MetadataType>
                </Metadata>
                <Metadata UniqueId="" Id="" Name="XmlContentText" Value="" Sequence="0">
                    <MetadataType>Specification</MetadataType>
                </Metadata>
            </MetadataList>
            <MetadataGroups />
            <Promotions />
            <Surcharge UniqueId="" Id="" Amount="0" />
            <CopyrightFee UniqueId="" Id="" Amount="0" />
            <ProductType>Bto</ProductType>
            <Height Value="0" UnitOfMeasure="Unknown" />
            <Length Value="0" UnitOfMeasure="Unknown" />
            <Width Value="0" UnitOfMeasure="Unknown" />
            <Weight Value="0" UnitOfMeasure="Unknown" />
            <AliasSkus />
            <TaxAmount UniqueId="" Id="" Amount="451.92" />
            <TaxAmountwithQty UniqueId="" Id="" Amount="0" />
            <ProductDiscount />
            <PscSegment>unknown</PscSegment>
            <BaseCatalogPrice UniqueId="" Id="" Amount="2152" />
            <BaseListPrice UniqueId="" Id="" Amount="2152" />
            <ListPrice UniqueId="" Id="" Amount="2603.92" />
            <CatalogFinalPrice UniqueId="" Id="" Amount="2603.92" />
            <PriceType>Unknown</PriceType>
        </RefreshedProduct>
        <SurchargeTaxFactor UniqueId="" Id="" Amount="0" />
        <CopyrightFeeTaxFactor UniqueId="" Id="" Amount="0" />
    </Item>
    </LineItems>
<ValidationErrors />

        <CreditRequestAmount UniqueId="" Id="" Amount="25259" />
        <CVResult />
    </Payment>
</Payments>
<Shipments>
    <Shipment
        xmlns:d3p1="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" d3p1:type="LSShipment" UniqueId="" Id="" AddressId="" IsDefault="false" ShippingInstructions="" ThirdPartyTrackingNo="" ShipmentNo="" ActualAdminData="" ActualProductionDate="" AcutalConsolidationDate="" ActualShipDate="" ActualDeliveryDate="" PlannedShipDate="" PlannedDeliveryDate="" OSSStatus="" StatusRefTime="" CarrierCode="LSCarrierCode" IsAssisted="false" ServiceLevelCode="LSServiceLevelCode" ServiceLevelDescCode="SS">
        <LineItems>
            <Id>1</Id>
            <Id>2</Id>
        </LineItems>
        <CarrierList />
        <EnhancedServiceList />
        <EnhancedService />
        <LsSkus>
            <LineItem UniqueId="" Id="1" Name="" DisplayName="" Description="" OSSStatus="" GroupId="" Quantity="1" ActualQty="0" AttachId="0" DynamicBunImageURL="" IsDisplayable="true" Availability="0" ValidatePrice="true" CurrentQty="0" FutureQty="0" ReservationQty="0" FutureUsed="false" IsValid="true" CampaignCode="" TaxLogic="Default" PriceIncludesRegulatoryFee="false" OID="0" DynamicBundleId="" DynamicBundleName="" DynamicBundleDescription="" Sequence="0" ActualLineItemId="" IsDynamicBundle="false" DynamicBundleQty="0" IsCouponApplicable="false" ParentSku="" isTaxRateChanged="false" ItemMaxQty="0">
                <DiscountCollection />
                <TaxItems />
                <IsExclude>false</IsExclude>
                <LineItemApportionedDiscount UniqueId="" Id="" Amount="0" />
                <SurchargeTaxFactor UniqueId="" Id="" Amount="0" />
                <CopyrightFeeTaxFactor UniqueId="" Id="" Amount="0" />
            </LineItem>
        </LsSkus>
    </Shipment>
</Shipments>
<Discounts />
<TaxItems>
    <LineItemTax UniqueId="" Id="0" Message="" Code="OM" Type="Product">
        <TotalAmount UniqueId="" Id="" Amount="0" />
        <SubTaxes>
        </SubTaxes>
    </LineItemTax>
    <LineItemTax UniqueId="" Id="1" Message="" Code="OM" Type="Product">
        <TotalAmount UniqueId="" Id="" Amount="0.2" />
        <SubTaxes>
                        </SubTaxes>
    </LineItemTax>
</TaxItems>
    <Compensations />
<SendSiebelTime>1901-01-01T00:00:00</SendSiebelTime>
<AssociateOpportunityTime>1901-01-01T00:00:00</AssociateOpportunityTime>
    </Addresses>
    <PhoneNumbers />
    <EmailAddresses>
        <Email UniqueId="" Id="SCEUE33685069" Address="administratie@entis.ai" IsDefault="false">
            <Locale>Work</Locale>
            <Status>Active</Status>
        </Email>
    </EmailAddresses>
    <ExternalKey>p1mfrp6tt34bsmpbpu9cgn4yduj61x5x</ExternalKey>
    <UserGuid>05FB4EDB-8CB3-4224-BB49-39628D21C6BF</UserGuid>
    <Type>External</Type>
    <RegistrationDate>2022-10-28T12:32:56</RegistrationDate>
    <PasswordExpirationDate>1901-01-01T00:00:00</PasswordExpirationDate>
    <SecurityQuestion1 />
    <SecurityAnswer1 />
    <SecurityQuestion2 />
    <SecurityAnswer2 />
    <SiebelContactID />
    <LastSiebelUpdatedDate>1901-01-01T00:00:00</LastSiebelUpdatedDate>
</CreatedFor>
<CreatedBy UniqueId="" Id="SCEU33285893" Name="AUTH\vanVegS" DisplayName="" Description="" FirstName="serge" MiddleInitial="" LastName="vegten" LastName2="" Salutation="" Language="nl" Notes="" UserTypeCode="" UserType="0" UserName="AUTH\vanVegS" PasswordHash="" Password="" UserSecuritySalt="" SecurityQuestion="" SecurityAnswer="" PrimaryAccountId="" Country="NL" PhoneticLastName="" PhoneticFirstName="" Gender="Unknown" DateOfBirth="1901-01-01T00:00:00" Occupation="" BusinessFunction="" PromoEmailConsent="" AdminEmailConsent="" FaxConsent="" Department="" CustomerSegment="Business" CompanyName="" CustomerSubSegment="Public" IsFarmingAccount="false">
    <EffectiveStartDate>1901-01-01T00:00:00</EffectiveStartDate>
    <EffectiveEndDate>1901-01-01T00:00:00</EffectiveEndDate>
    <Status>Active</Status>
    <Created UniqueId="" Id="" ActionPerformed="created" PerformedBy="AUTH\canovasl" PerformedDate="2020-11-16T16:40:41" ItemSource="CallCenter" />
    <LastModified UniqueId="" Id="" ActionPerformed="modified" PerformedBy="AUTH\vanVegS" PerformedDate="2022-11-22T13:47:04.0639606+00:00" ItemSource="CallCenter" />
    <ExtendedProperties />
    <Addresses>
        <Address UniqueId="" Id="SCEUA35660872" Name="" DisplayName="" Description="" AddressName="" CustomerTitle="" SalutationKey="" FirstName="" Area="" TaxId="" AlternateShippingContact="" MiddleInitial="" LastName="" CompanyName="" Line1="" Line2="" Line3="" City="" Region="" PostalCode="" Country="NL" IsDefault="false" LastName2="" AddressAssociationType="User" Locale="Unknown" CRSID="" DepartmentName="" PhoneticCompanyName="" PhoneticFirstName="" PhoneticLastName="" Email="" CYSISID="" StateName="" CRSStatusCode="RequestNotCalled" CRSErrorCode="" AVRStatusCode="SE00000800" AVRErrorCode="" IsVerified="false">
            <EffectiveStartDate>1901-01-01T00:00:00</EffectiveStartDate>
            <EffectiveEndDate>1901-01-01T00:00:00</EffectiveEndDate>
            <Status>Active</Status>
            <ExtendedProperties />
            <AddressType>Billing</AddressType>
            <CompanyPresident />
            </Address>
        </Addresses>
    <PhoneNumbers />
    <EmailAddresses>
        <Email UniqueId="" Id="SCEUE33286377" Address="serge.van.vegten@hp.com" IsDefault="false">
            <Locale>Work</Locale>
            <Status>Active</Status>
        </Email>
    </EmailAddresses>
    <ExternalKey>U</ExternalKey>
    <UserGuid>0DFFDA3D-B811-4381-8E81-DAFF3349CEC9</UserGuid>
    <Type>Internal</Type>
    <RegistrationDate>2020-11-16T16:40:41</RegistrationDate>
    <PasswordExpirationDate>1901-01-01T00:00:00</PasswordExpirationDate>
    <SecurityQuestion1 />
    <SecurityAnswer1 />
    <SecurityQuestion2 />
    <SecurityAnswer2 />
    <SiebelContactID />
    <LastSiebelUpdatedDate>1901-01-01T00:00:00</LastSiebelUpdatedDate>
</CreatedBy>
<UpdatedBy UniqueId="" Id="" Name="" DisplayName="" Description="" FirstName="" MiddleInitial="" LastName="" LastName2="" Salutation="" Language="" Notes="" UserTypeCode="" UserType="0" UserName="" PasswordHash="" Password="" UserSecuritySalt="" SecurityQuestion="" SecurityAnswer="" PrimaryAccountId="" Country="" PhoneticLastName="" PhoneticFirstName="" Gender="Unknown" DateOfBirth="1901-01-01T00:00:00" Occupation="" BusinessFunction="" Department="" CustomerSegment="Consumer" CompanyName="" CustomerSubSegment="Public" IsFarmingAccount="false">
    <EffectiveStartDate>1901-01-01T00:00:00</EffectiveStartDate>
    <EffectiveEndDate>1901-01-01T00:00:00</EffectiveEndDate>
    <Status>Active</Status>
    <ExtendedProperties />
    <Addresses />
    <PhoneNumbers />
    <EmailAddresses />
    <ExternalKey />
    <UserGuid />
    <Type>Unknown</Type>
    <RegistrationDate>1901-01-01T00:00:00</RegistrationDate>
    <PasswordExpirationDate>1901-01-01T00:00:00</PasswordExpirationDate>
    <LastSiebelUpdatedDate>1901-01-01T00:00:00</LastSiebelUpdatedDate>
</UpdatedBy>
    <PreferredShipDate>1901-01-01T00:00:00</PreferredShipDate>
<QuoteIds>
    <Id />
</QuoteIds>
```

```
SELECT X.Y.value('ProductType[1]','VARCHAR(20)') AS ProductType, X.Y.value('ISDRCEligible[1]','VARCHAR(20)') AS ISDRCEligible,
X.Y.value('ISDRCApplied[1]','VARCHAR(20)') AS ISDRCApplied,
X.Y.value('type[1]','NVARCHAR(20)') AS type,
X.Y.value('IsAncillary[1]','VARCHAR(20)') AS  IsAncillary,X.Y.value('IsSameQtyReq[1]','VARCHAR(20)') AS IsSameQtyReq,X.Y.value('TaxCode[1]','VARCHAR(20)') AS TaxCode,
X.Y.value('Country[1]','VARCHAR(20)') AS Country
FROM (
SELECT top 100000 CAST(SerializedOrder AS XML) as SerializedOrder 
FROM TransactionOrder WITH(NOLOCK))a
CROSS APPLY a.SerializedOrder.nodes('Order/LineItems/Item') AS X(Y)
WHERE X.Y.value('ProductType[1]','VARCHAR(20)')='Bto' AND X.Y.value('ISDRCEligible[1]','VARCHAR(20)')='true' AND 
X.Y.value('ISDRCApplied[1]','VARCHAR(20)')='true' AND --X.Y.value('type[1]','NVARCHAR(20)')='CarePack' AND
X.Y.value('IsAncillary[1]','VARCHAR(20)')='true' AND X.Y.value('IsSameQtyReq[1]','VARCHAR(20)')='true' AND
X.Y.value('TaxCode[1]','VARCHAR(20)')='OM' AND X.Y.value('Country[1]','VARCHAR(20)')='NL'
```

Comment: when i run the select query am getting null values for those tags, Can some one help here?

Comment: How are you extracting any values from the included XML at all? The current XML is incomplete and has errors (such as missing/unbalanced tags) when you try to `CAST` it to the XML data type. Please [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74871144/edit) your question to include valid XML.

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).